# Font used for text in first and third line

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification

What is the font used for the first line of text and the third line of text in these images? They appear to be the same font.

In the first image it's `NO. 06` and `SEASONING`

In the second image it's `NO. 09` and `HERB` and `NO.19` & `SEASONING`

In the third it's `NO. 02` and `HERB`

The G and digits are unique. myfonts identification service could not find a match. Can you help?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the font is curved on bottles, it's a bit hard to use online tools to identify the it. Like you said, you have already tried that.

So the only other way to find it, in my opinion, is either someone already know about this font with experience or you do some 'hit and trial' to browse similar looking fonts.

I did same and here's what I've found:

---

Almost similar typeface - **Glacial Indifference** (regular)

[image]

I feel it's actually the font being used in your images *(the first line of text and the third lines of text you mentioned)*. I found it at a few sites but not really sure if it's free or paid for commercial use. You can simply search it online and you can find it at websites like `Dafont.com`.

---

Free similar typeface:

**Jost** (available at `fonts.google.com`
[image]

---

Similar typefaces (paid):

- **Lemon Milk Pro**
- **Morn**

(both available at `myfonts.com`)

Comment: You're correct. It's Glacial Indifference. You can tell from the digits. The 6, 9 and 3. The image with the 3 and 6 isn't posted here. I made a lable in Indesign and its just the same as the ones in the image.

Comment: @Norman yeah everything was matching. I just didn't have enough proof.

Answer (score 1):

Lowest common denominator.... meaning.. most often people *won't* use really obscure, little known, fonts. I mean, that *can* certainly be the case. But the best place to start looking is with more commonly used typefaces. First default app/OS fonts, then branch to more widely used typefaces...

The rounded O and more oblong 0 (zero), combined with the R lead me to believe it may be in the **[Futura](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/futura-pt)** family... And I think it's *all* the *same* typeface, merely different weights.

[image]

Comment: Futura comes pretty close. But the font that's a perfect match is Glacial Indifference.